# How can I create disk for smaller files with good read/write speeds?

Tags: inode, mkfs

I'm trying to find the best way to store lots of small files on a volume, without hitting the inode limits. I created a new drive with:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -N 100000000 /dev/device
```

and this correctly shows:

```
/dev/device  100040704 13929894 86110810   14% /mnt/websites2
```

However, it seems to have made a fair hit to the speed for read/writes on that drive. I was doing some research, and came across:

https://www.tecmint.com/increase-disk-inode-number-in-linux/

They suggest:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -T largefile /dev/device
```

What is the option for "small files"? I can't seem to find any documentation on what the values of `-T` can be? Also - any other suggestions on how to configure a drive for LOTS of small files (~3-10kb each), would be much appreciated!

Comment: You should strongly consider using a different filesystem, such as XFS.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks. What is the benefit of XFS? I'm afraid I'm not that knowledgable in the different types of filesystems

Comment: How many is "lots" of files, order of magnitude? What is the distribution of files sizes?  How many IOPS is the workload? What are you comparing to where this is a "fair hit to the speed": what was the other configuration, and quantify what the difference is?

Comment: @JohnMahowald there are about 150 million files. The main hit I saw was the CPU load jumping quite a lot. Originally I stored the HTML in the MySQL table, but then I had problems with the drive filling up (and I didn't want to keep upgrading the server spec to get more disk space). In terms of the setup - I split them into 5 layers. So "foobar.com" would be put in `/f/o/o/b/a/foobar.com.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lots of small files it's better to use,
`mkfs.ext4 -T news /dev/device`

There is also `mkfs.ext4 -T small /dev/device` but this sets a small inode size.

The labels for `-T` in mkfs.ext4 can be found in `/etc/mke2fs.conf`. You can find more info using `man mke2fs` and `man mke2fs.conf`

Apparently you need a large inode number and a small bytes/inode ratio. You could make a new label in `/etc/mke2fs.conf` and try some configurations to get the optimal performance for your scenario.